# How to get the nth table in webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I use webbrowser control and want to get the **n** *th* table in the document. `webbrowser1.Document` has arrays of elements for `Forms`, `Images`, `Links` ... but not for tables.

There is no Id for the table and I need to access the live element, I mean `HtmlAgilityPack` doesn't help me.

Comment: what are you getting in `echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize");` ?

Comment: 10M and 15M for post_max_size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HtmlAgilityPack` to find the nth table. something like

```
   Node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]");
```

Then use the code described in this post to find the corresponding live element [Gettig Htmlelement based on HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833160/)