# Gettig Htmlelement based on HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

I use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the html document of a webbrowser control.
I am able to find my desired HtmlNode, but after getting the HtmlNode, I want to retun the corresponding HtmlElement in the WebbrowserControl.Document.

In fact HtmlAgilityPack parse an offline copy of the live document, while I want to access live elements of the webbrowser Control to access some rendered attributes like `currentStyle` or `runtimeStyle`

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
var some_nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"); 
// this selection could be more sophisticated 
// and the answer shouldn't relay on it.
foreach (HtmlNode node in some_nodes)
{
   HtmlElement live_element = CorrespondingElementFromWebBrowserControl(node);
   // CorrespondingElementFromWebBrowserControl is what I am searching for
}
```

If the element had a specific attribute it could be easy but I want a solution which works on any element.

Please help me what can I do about it.

Comment: What do you mean with return the corresponding htmlnode in the control document?
Which node is the matching one and in which way do you want to display it?

Comment: @Xenogenesis I offered a code in the question to convey my meaning.

Comment: The problem is that you have to specify which search conditions your needed element should match
With this conditions, for example all subnodes that are links or that contain a 'k' in their element name, you can use a recursive loop through the childnodes of `item`

Comment: @Xenogenesis I edited my question, its not about match, just the corresponding element. I can find any element in the HtmlAgilityPack but I need a pointer to the real element in web browser control, I wonder why the HtmlAgilityPack itself doesn't provide this relation! it just process an offline copy of the html of the control in the format of htmlNode!

Comment: Give and example of your HTML and which nodes you are trying to get .. that will help us to help you

Comment: Ah I think I've got you!
You are trying to edit the shown document in realtime aren't you?

Comment: @Xenogenesis, yes, right, in fact I want to get runtime style or currentstyle of the elements in webbrowser control. HtmlAgilityPack lets me to find any node, but the currentStyle works on real elements in browser I think. Beside, I thought my post gives the same meaning, if not please suggest an edit to convey the purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `XPath` attribute of the `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode` shows the nodes on the path from root to the node. For example `\div[1]\div[2]\table[0]`. You can traverse this path in the live document to find the corresponding live element. However this path may not be precise as HtmlAgilityPack removes some tags like `<form>` then before using this solution add the omitted tags back using

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

struct DocNode  
{
    public string Name;
    public int Pos;
}
///// structure to hold the name and position of each node in the path
```

The following method finds the live element according to the XPath

```
    static public HtmlElement GetLiveElement(HtmlNode node, HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        var pattern = @"/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]"; // like div[1]
        // Parse the XPath to extract the nodes on the path
        var matches = Regex.Matches(node.XPath, pattern); 
        List<DocNode> PathToNode = new List<DocNode>();
        foreach (Match m in matches) // Make a path of nodes
        {
            DocNode n = new DocNode();
            n.Name = n.Name = m.Groups[1].Value;
            n.Pos = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[2].Value)-1;
            PathToNode.Add(n); // add the node to path 
        }

        HtmlElement elem = null; //Traverse to the element using the path
        if (PathToNode.Count > 0)
        {
            elem = doc.Body; //begin from the body
            foreach (DocNode n in PathToNode)
            {
                //Find the corresponding child by its name and position
                elem = GetChild(elem, n);                    
            }
        }
        return elem;
    }
```

the code for GetChild Method used above

```
    public static HtmlElement GetChild(HtmlElement el, DocNode node)
    {
        // Find corresponding child of the elemnt 
        // based on the name and position of the node
        int childPos = 0;
        foreach (HtmlElement child in el.Children)
        {
            if (child.TagName.Equals(node.Name, 
               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (childPos == node.Pos)
                {
                    return child;
                }
                childPos++;
            }                
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact there seems to be no direct possibility to change the document directly in the webbroser control.
But you can extract the html from it, mnipulate it and write it back again like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.DocumentText);

foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes) {
    node.Attributes.Add("TEST", "TEST");
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb)) {
    doc.Save(sw);
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString();
}
```

For direct manipulation you can maybe use the unmanaged pointer `webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument` to the document, but this is outside of my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you anyway, you didn't mention the relation between sb ad the node in your code... but you mean to add a specific attribute to the node and then write it back and search according to that attribute? However currently i solved my problem in similar way, I wanted to get the runtime font of the selected node and now I do that by searching the inner text of the node in web browser control...

Answer (score 2):

HtmlAgilityPack definitely can't provide access to nodes in live HTML directly. Since you said there is no distinct style/class/id on the element you have to walk through the nodes manually and find matches.

Assuming HTML is reasonably valid (so both browser and HtmlAgilityPack perform normalization similarly) you can walk pairs of elements starting from the root of both trees and selecting the same child node.

Basically you can build "position-based" XPath to node in one tree and select it in another tree. Xpath would look something like (depending you want to pay attention to just positions or position and node name):

```
 "/*[1]/*[4]/*[2]/*[7]"
 "/body/div[2]/span[1]/p[3]"
```

Steps:

1. In using `HtmlNode` you've found collect all parent nodes up to the root.
2. Get root of element of HTML in browser
3. for each level of children find position of corresponding child on HtmlNodes collection on step 1 in its parent and than find live HtmlElement among children of current live node.
4. Move to newly found child and go back to 3 till found node you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I will check your answer, beside you can review my edited question to vote it, I modified it and mentioned my real purpose is to access currentStyle of the live element.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion as the following answer!